# Cores of black holes

Tags: black-holes

White dwarves and neutron stars are held together by degeneracy pressure, which eventually breaks down.
But even though space time curvature causes a black hole to form, could there be some other structure matter could take, only elucidated by a correct quantum theory of gravity, where the pressure is so much that it counteracts the space time curvature, and forms some kind of stable structure maybe the size of an apple?  Is that even a possibility?
Otherwise, what the heck happens to all that *stuff*?

Answer (score 3):

> Is that even a possibility?

We can’t rule it out. Since we don’t have an agreed on and experimentally verified theory of quantum gravity, we just don’t know what happens at the centre of a black hole.

> Otherwise, what the heck happens to all that stuff?

Indeed - that is exactly why we need a theory of quantum gravity. Maybe there is some new state of matter at the centre of a black hole. Maybe everything gets eaten up by a herd of ten dimensional pink unicorns. We just don’t know.